# Optional condition in join clause - Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have below linq query

```
 var resultGuardian = from s in _db.Students
     join sg in _db.StudentGuardians on s.StudentID equals sg.StudentID
     join g in _db.Guardians on sg.GuardianId equals g.GuardianId
     join lr in _db.luRelationTypes on sg.RelationTypeID equals lr.RelationTypeID
     join ga in _db.GuardianAddresses on g.GuardianId equals ga.GuardianId
     join ad in _db.Addresses on ga.AddressID equals ad.AddressID
     join lt in _db.luAddressTypes on ad.AddressTypeID equals lt.AddressTypeID
     join lg in _db.luGenders on g.GenderID equals (int?)lg.GenderID into ssts
     from gdnr in ssts.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where
         s.TenantID == tenantid && sg.TenantID == tenantid && g.TenantID == tenantid &&
         s.StatusId == (int?)Extension.StatusType.Active //1
         && g.StatusID == (int?)Extension.StatusType.Active &&
         lr.StatusID == (int?)Extension.StatusType.Active && lr.TenantID == tenantid &&
         s.StudentID == sid
     select new
     {
         g.FirstName,
         g.LastName,
         IsPrimary = sg.IsPrimaryGuardian,
         g.Education,
         g.Email,
         g.Phone,
         lr.RelationCD,
         ga.IsStudentAddress,
         gdnr.GenderCD,
         lt.AddressName,
         ad.Address1,
         ad.Address2,
         ad.City,
         ad.State,
         ad.Zipcode

     };
```

In above query when `ad.AddressTypeID` is `null`, it is not returning any result.

I have requirement if `ad.AddressTypeID` is `null`,than from `LuAddressTypes` fetch default record where `AddressTypeCd=1`. If I try this way

```
join lt in LuAddressTypes on ad.AddressTypeID equals lt.AddressTypeID into v1
from v2 in v1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
     {      
         v2.AddressName,
         g.Phone,..

     });
```

in result **`v2.AddressName`** always returning `null`. I am unable to specify `AddressTypeCd=1` `where` condition as well. `AddressTypeCd=1` is not `ad.AddressTypeID`.

I need `v2.AddressName` where `AddressTypeCd=1`. How can I do that?
Find related entities [all related entities](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AoU8wqJTZgnPqxNGTCTaOk7_zaOq)

Comment: search for linq left outer join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: @AccessDenied - Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Please post the involved entity classes. Also fix the sample query  - currently it's using some not existing aliases - `ga`, `g`, `lr`.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Sure, doing it.

Comment: Btw, if the `AddressTypeCd` here *"I have requirement if `ad.AddressTypeID` is `null`,than from `LuAddressTypes` fetch default record where `AddressTypeCd=1`"* actually means `AddressTypeID`, then simply use `join lt in LuAddressTypes on ad.AddressTypeID ?? 1 equals lt.AddressTypeID`

Comment: @IvanStoev -Wow! It's working. You are amazing. Feel free to write as an answer. Please mention how it is taking `AddressTypeCd=1` on `LuAddressTypes` table only. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I notice above solution considering `ad.AddressTypeID ?? 1` to `AddressTypeID` column only not `AddressTypeCd`. It worked me coincidentally as I have matching data. 
You said - `AddressTypeCd=1` actually means `AddressTypeID`, No.

Comment: You want a conditional join, @AccessDenied already gave you a big hint : go with outer join :)

Comment: @Florian - As for as I know in `linq to entities` there is no outer join.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Linq will create a SQL request at the end, even if you can't write "outer join" with linq syntax, the easy way is to use `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, by doing so Linq will produce an outer join. Do you need help to write it ?

Comment: If you check my question properly :) I have done that, but not getting expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the standard LINQ `join`, but in LINQ to Entities you could use the alternative join syntax based on correlated `Where` - EF is smart enough to translate it to `JOIN`.

In your case, instead of

```
join lt in _db.luAddressTypes on ad.AddressTypeID equals lt.AddressTypeID
```

you could use

```
from lt in _db.luAddressTypes.Where(lt => ad.AddressTypeID == lt.AddressTypeID
    || (ad.AddressTypeID == null && lt.AddressTypeCd == 1))
```

which is translated to something like this

```sql
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LuAddressTypes] AS [Extent3]
    ON ([Extent2].[AddressTypeID] = [Extent3].[AddressTypeID])
        OR (([Extent2].[AddressTypeID] IS NULL) AND (1 = [Extent3].[AddressTypeCd]))
```

If you want `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, simply add `.DefaultIfEmpty()` at the end of the above line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is returning multiple records. Can you please suggest me how to avoid this.

Comment: Add `.Take(1)` :) It would change the `JOIN` to `CROSS APPLY`, but the effect should be the same.